# Re-format JSON data and grouping data by date range

Tags: php, json, sorting

Hi I have question about logic and I can't solve this.
I have json data and I want to re-format by grouping data if Price and Type is same on next day
Please check my Json data below

```
[
 {
   "price": 1000,
   "date": "2021-03-13",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1000,
   "date": "2021-03-14",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1000,
   "date": "2021-03-15",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1300,
   "date": "2021-03-16",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1000,
   "date": "2021-03-17",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1300,
   "date": "2021-03-18",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1500,
   "date": "2021-03-19",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1500,
   "date": "2021-03-20",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1500,
   "date": "2021-03-21",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 1500,
   "date": "2021-03-22",
   "type": "A"
 },
 {
   "price": 2000,
   "date": "2021-03-13",
   "type": "B"
 },
 {
   "price": 2000,
   "date": "2021-03-14",
   "type": "B"
 },
 {
   "price": 2000,
   "date": "2021-03-15",
   "type": "B"
 },
 {
   "price": 2000,
   "date": "2021-03-16",
   "type": "B"
 },
 {
   "price": 2000,
   "date": "2021-03-17",
   "type": "B"
 }
]
```

I want to re-format like this (grouping data with same Price and Type)

```
[
     [
       "type"=> "A"
       "price"=> 1000
       "startDate"=> "2021-03-13"
       "endDate"=> "2021-03-15"
     ],
     [
       "type"=> "A"
       "price"=> 1300
       "startDate"=> "2021-03-16"
       "endDate"=> "2021-03-16"
     ],
     [
       "type"=> "A"
       "price"=> 1000
       "startDate"=> "2021-03-17"
       "endDate"=> "2021-03-17"
     ],
     [
       "type"=> "A"
       "price"=> 1300
       "startDate"=> "2021-03-18"
       "endDate"=> "2021-03-18"
     ],
     [
       "type"=> "A"
       "price"=> 1500
       "startDate"=> "2021-03-19"
       "endDate"=> "2021-03-22"
     ],
     [
       "type"=> "B"
       "price"=> 2000
       "startDate"=> "2021-03-13"
       "endDate"=> "2021-03-17"
     ],

]
```

For now I only have idea about create temp array and loop json data, but I don't have idea how to convert to startDate and endDate

Answer (score 0):

You will need a temp assoc. array, as "cache" of sort, and result array. For each type, note the price and start date in the cache, use type as a key.

Illustration of the cache assoc. array:

```php
$cache = [
    "A"=>[
        "price"=>1000,
        "date"=>"2021-03-13",
        "type"=>"A"
     ],
]
```

First, sort the array by date. Then loop the array and create your "cache" entries in the temp assoc. array. When creating, the "date" is your "startDate". Because the key "A" doesn't exist yet, you know you don't need to compare anything.

But if the type of the item is already present in the cache (few loops down the road), you know it's not its first appearance in the loop, so now you compare the price.

If the price is the same, you update "endDate" in your cache. If the price is different, you put the item from the cache to the result array - you already have both startDate and endDate there. You may want to delete the "date" key from the item, before putting itto the result.

And finally, you update the item in the cache with new startDate and price (and delete endDate, or re-create the entire item) and start over with further items of your source array.